# Automapper mapping between different datatypes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have below piece of code where I have to map user.email (string datatype) with userProfile.Email.email datamember.

`user.UserEmails.Add(new UserEmail { Email = email });`

How could I do this mapping?

Comment: Post your code. Have you tried something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have your `User` class:

```
class User
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and the class `UserProfile` and class `Email`:

```
class UserProfile
{
    public Email Email { get; set; }
}

class Email
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do something the following:

```
// create mapping
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserProfile>()
      .ForMember(up => up.Email, opt => opt.MapFrom(u => new UserEmail { Email = u.Email }));

// map the entity
var userProfile = Mapper.Map<UserProfile>(user);
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the core logic for mapping from entity to model. Hope it helps

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceDataType, DestinationDataType>();
var YourEntityData = GetMyData();//this method will return data of type "SourceDataType"
DestinationDataType modelObj= 
              Mapper.Map<SourceDataType, DestinationDataType>(YourEntityData);
```

Comment: C# allows you to specfy the type explicitly for a variable so instead of `var YourEntityData = GetMyData();//this method will return data of type "SourceDataType"` you can just say `SourceDataType YourEntityData = GetMyData();`

Comment: Yup Thanks...
I know that friend but I don't know will it effect performance if I use `var` ???

Comment: @mauliksakhare Using var will have zero performance influence. When the code is compiled, it won't be "var" anymore, but the type that the compiler infers.